# if statement in bash not executing

Tags: bash, if-statement, statements

I am a beginner is bash and i really need some help here.The conditional part of the script is not executing for some reason.
Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
#Checking Os
os=$(lsb_release -si)
echo $os
if [ $os == "CentOs" ]; then
echo 'success'
fi
```

Now part till echo $os works fine and out is

> CentOs

but 'success' don't get output :(

Any idea why if part don't get executed.What is wrong with the syntax.I get no errors whatsoever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux is case sensitive. Running "lsb_release -a" on my CentOS install results in "CentOS" - note that the trailing "S" is uppercase.  Change your code to test for the properly capitalized string, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Checking Os
os=$(lsb_release -si)

# !quote variables when passing them to commands like echo!
echo "$os"

# A space between ] and ; Quote "$os". Note: = instead of == is OK as well.
# Note that it's not CentOs, it's CentOS
if [ "$os" == "CentOS" ] ; then
  echo 'success'
fi
```

The ultimate reference: [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Comment: Hhmm. My bash manual says, that `=` and `==` inside a conditional expression are equivalent.

Comment: @A.H. Thx for the tip! I didn't know this. Also I would not say that I'm a bash guru. Just wanted to help the newbie opener a little bit. Have updated the post to prevent from giving useless information.....

Comment: Thanks but it still didn't work , sucess is still not echoed on my end , Only value of $os is display